# Ruby/Minitest: How can I run #setup for all tests but one?

Tags: ruby, minitest

I have a test file that looks something like this:

```
class ThingsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    ...
  end

  # Test 1
  test 'it should do something' do
    ...
  end

  # Test 2
  test 'it should do something else' do
    ...
  end

  ...

  # Test 50
  test 'it should do another thing' do
    ...
  end
end
```

For tests 1 to 49, I want the setup method to fire. However, for the final test, I do not. Is there a way to prevent `#setup` from running for that final test?

Answer (score 2):

You could either create another class and extract your 50th test case there or use custom setup method:

```
def my_setup
  ...
end

test 'test1' do
  my_setup
end

...

test 'test49' do
  my_setup
end

test 'test50' do
# no my_setup here
end
```

You can also switch to [rspec](http://rspec.info/) where you can easily separate test cases with `describe`s and `context` like:

```
describe 'block1' do
  before do
  #setup here
  end

  it 'test1' do
  end

  ...
end

describe 'block2' do
  it 'test50' do
  end
end
```